# Unix shell script: Inject text when "text pattern" is found

Tags: regex, shell, unix, cat

Say I have two files:
- data.txt
- report.txt

The report contains a text with some "placeholders", example:

```
HPLC results for sample: <insert-sample-id-here>, elements analyzed: <insert-element-name>
```

The data file contains a series of "key/value" lines:

```
sampleID: 123456abc
elementName: genericThickeningAgent
```

Not a computer whiz here, but I know the task of "find and replace" can be automated by the computer; What sort of command should be used to "rewrite report.txt after replacing the placeholders with the value of the matching pairs from my data file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current form of the file, it would be hard to match values from data file to placeholders in report file, because placeholder `<insert-sample-id-here>` is different than `sampleID` from data.txt. The same for `<insert-element-name>` being not equal to `elementName`.

But assuming you have `data.txt` in a different form:

```
insert-sample-id-here: 123456abc
insert-element-name: genericThickeningAgent
```

(so if keys in `data.txt` are matching placeholders in `report.txt`) you can use this command:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "s/<$1>/$2/g\n" if /^(.*?):\s+(.*)$/' data.txt | \
    xargs -I% perl -p -i -w -e "%" report.txt
```

Which will replace all the placeholders in `report.txt`:

```
$ cat report.txt
results for sample: 123456abc, elements analyzed: genericThickeningAgent
```

Comment: Wow this is actually more than I could have asked for! I thought it would be necessary to write the "find and replace" for each pair. I'll see if it's possible to change the report template. Thanks a lot for your solution, it's so good!